# icheck not working with angular js

Tags: angularjs, icheck

Actually, there are similar kind of question at here. Solution of that questions are working. So, I picked the solutions from there and I put at my local pc. But, it's not worked! Then I make a [new Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G4o3EQMqG07WgDrv9bhy?p=preview) (copied [icheck-plugin](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) newly) and put the solution into there. But, I noticed at this time the plunker is not working too. I've add class by directive:

```
element.iCheck({
    checkboxClass: "checkbox-default"
});
```

But, it seem that the class is not achieved if I see via inspect element. Why, this is happened and how can I fix this?

Comment: dont really have any time to explain right now but here is a working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/RNOuiWKmEfoSEHdN3GMg?p=preview , anyone is welcome to write up an explanation as an answer. note that i deleted last bits of icheck plugin which automatically converts checkboxes using jquery.

Comment: Well, after seeing your solution, I have modified just this line at my plunker: <input type="checkbox" id=""  icheck> and it works! It's very frustrating for me as a new anguler learner as I haven't found anywhere at icheck plugin that I have to add the word 'icheck' in input box! Thanks by the way..

Comment: The easiest way to get the iCheck work with AngularJS is by writing a directive that will hooks on to all required event exposed by the plugin. Here is such directive written to watch the "Disable" attribute, Ifchanged, IfClicked events. It works well in all scenarios like using it in ngRepeat etc., http://davidsekar.com/angularjs/angularjs-directive-for-jquery-icheck